How to Understand the Decompositions of Representations of $A_n$.
In short, I would like a thorough walk-through as to how representations of $A_{n}$ are decomposed from the pure linear algebra perspective. For example, a representation of an $A_2$ quiver is a linear map $A_{\alpha}$ between two vector spaces. This representation decomposes into
$$1 \to 0, 0 \to 1, 1 \to 1$$
I'd appreciate a top to bottom explanation of the process for $A_2$ and perhaps $A_3$. The source I'm using (Etingof) doesn't make clear why we use complements to the kernel and Image of $A_{\alpha}$ in the procedure of computing the indecomposables.

I am going to write the answer just for $A_2$. For $A_3$, it depends on the direction of the arrows, and even for any one orientation is tedious to write out in this much detail.
Let's assume we start with a representation $X$ of the $A_2$ quiver, which we can think of as a linear map $X_\alpha$ from $X_1$ to $X_2$. I'm going to assume our representations are over $\mathbb C$; any field would work just as well.
When we are trying to express $X$ as a direct sum of indecomposable representations, the essence of what we are doing is finding a way to change bases so that the structure of $X$ becomes very transparent and very simple.
Let's first look for copies of the indecomposable representation $\mathbb C \rightarrow 0$ inside $X$. What does such a copy look like? Well, it would be a one-dimensional subspace of $X_1$ which is sent to zero by $X_\alpha$. In other words, it is part of the kernel of $X_\alpha$. So, what we realize is that we should choose a basis for $X_1$ that includes a basis of the kernel. Let's call that basis $k_1,\dots,k_s$. Once we've decided to include $k_1,\dots,k_s$ in our basis for $X_1$, though, we also need a basis for the rest of $X_1$ --- that's where we need to think about a basis for a complement of the kernel.
Let $V$ be some complement of the kernel, and choose a basis $v_1,\dots,v_r$ of $V$. The vectors $v_i$ are being sent by $X_\alpha$ to vectors in $X_2$ which are non-zero, because the $v_i$ are not in the kernel. And in fact, because $v_1,\dots,v_r$ are in $V$ which is a complement of the kernel, no linear combination of the $v_i$ is sent to zero. Thus, the images of the $v_i$ are linearly independent in $X_2$. Let's call their images $w_1,\dots,w_r$. Those images are a basis of the image of $X_\alpha$, because $X_1$ is a direct sum of $V$ and the kernel of $X_\alpha$, and the kernel of $X_\alpha$ isn't contributing anything to the image.
We aren't done, because $w_1,\dots,w_r$ might not be a basis of $X_2$. We want to extend $w_1,\dots,w_r$ to a basis for $X_2$. To do this, choose a complement of the image of $X_\alpha$ in $X_2$, and choose a basis for that, say $c_1,\dots,c_t$.
Now consider what $X_\alpha$ looks like with respect to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_r,k_1,\dots,k_s$ for $X_1$ and $w_1,\dots,w_r,c_1,\dots,c_t$ for $X_2$. What we see is that the matrix for $X_\alpha$ is an $r\times r$ identity block in the top left, and zero elsewhere. With respect to this basis, we see that $X_\alpha$ consists of $r$ copies of $\mathbb C \xrightarrow{1} \mathbb C$, $s$ copies of $\mathbb C\rightarrow 0$ and $t$ copies of $0\rightarrow \mathbb C$.
